# Query for showing stock as of given date in the past

Tags: mysql, join

I am developing software for warehouse management.

I got three tables: `itemstock, documents, doc_pcs`

`itemstock` fields (not all of them are shown):

- `rfid_no` (which is unique and primary key)
- `item_name`
- `status`

`documents` fields:

- `id`
- `doc_date`
- `doc_type`

`doc_pcs` fields:

- `id`
- `id_doc` | these two are primary key
- `pos`    | (`id_doc` is connected to `documents.id`)
- `rfid_no` (from `itemstock.rfid_no`)

First table is for collecting records of items, nothing is ever erased from this table, there's just status change when something happens with particular item (goes out to client, comes back etc).

`Documents` and `doc_pcs` tables store document data.

`doc_type` is for marking whether items on document were going in or out of the warehouse.

The problem is: 
I need to create query that shows all the stock as of given date.

In other words: 
It should show all items from today's `itemstock` with `status=6` ("stored") **MINUS** records with `rfid_no` that have matches in `doc_pcs` related to `documents` dated between *today* and a *given date* and with `doc_type="out"`  **PLUS**  records with `rfid_no` that have matches in `doc_pcs` related to `documents` dated between *today* and a *given date* and with `doc_type="in"`

Was searching for any clue here and there for few days now and I could not find anything that will lead me to any solution. I will be gratefull for any help!

Sample data:

`itemstock` (as of today):

```
00300D0909DA, "tshirt", 6
00300D0909DB, "apron", 6 
00300D0909DC, "tshirt", 6
00300D0909DD, "trousers", 6
00300D0909DE, "tshirt", 1
00300D0909DF, "trousers", 1
00300D0909E0, "trousers", 6
```

`documents`:

```
0,2015-08-01,"in"
1,2015-08-02,"in"
2,2015-08-03,"out"
3,2015-08-04,"in"
4,2015-08-05,"out"
5,2015-08-06,"in"
```

`doc_pcs`:

```
0, 1, 00300D0909DA
0, 2, 00300D0909DE
1, 1, 00300D0909DF
1, 2, 00300D0909DD
2, 1, 00300D0909DE
3, 1, 00300D0909DB
4, 1, 00300D0909DF
5, 1, 00300D0909DC
5, 2, 00300D0909E0
```

query results for given `doc_date=2015-08-04` including fields `rfid_no` and `item_name` should be:

```
00300D0909DA, "tshirt"
00300D0909DB, "apron" 
00300D0909DD, "trousers"
00300D0909DF, "trousers"
```

EDIT:
I've managed to make following query but it executes endlessly hence I believe something is wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.rfid_no 
 FROM itemstock c LEFT JOIN doc_pcs d 
  ON c.rfid_no=d.rfid_no 
   WHERE c.status=6 
OR 
 (d.id IN 
  (SELECT dk.id 
   FROM documents dk 
    WHERE DATE(dk.doc_date)>='2015-08-04' 
    AND dk.doc_type="out") 
AND 
 d.id NOT IN 
 (SELECT dk.id 
  FROM documents dk 
   WHERE DATE(dk.doc_date)>='2015-08-04' 
    AND dk.doc_type="in"))
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you are trying to do.  A SQL Fiddle also helps.

Comment: Good point. I'm going to post it in few minutes.

Comment: I've added sample of query that I tried but still no results. Any tip?

Comment: Still nothing. Currently I'm trying RIGHT JOIN along with FULL OUTER JOIN approach.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could either go from today's values and work backwards or you could start from 'day 0' and work forwards. By storing the stock count as of 'today' you are denormalizing the data so I'd opt for the second approach (and maybe you could save yourself a table).

Assume that as of 'day 0' all stock is empty. To get the stock count as of a given date you would (p-query):

```
select sum((select count inbound where date <= inventory_date) - (select count outbound where date <= inventory_date))
```

Comment: I understand using this approach gives me the quantity of items as of given date. However I need to have the list of all the items stored as of given date instead. Like in my example, not aggregates (such us: "trousers, 2 pcs") but every single item listed. It's important for us to know what and when happened with every single item. I'm not sure if I explained vividly enough.